# How to prevent MariaDB to install when installing MySQL-Server?

Tags: mysql, installation, debian, mariadb

I am trying to install MySQL Server in a Debian 9 installation and apt-get insists to install this mariadb-client-10.1 through:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer     required:
  libmecab2 libtext-template-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
default-mysql-client default-mysql-server mariadb-client-10.1
mariadb-server-10.1
Suggested packages:
mailx mariadb-test netcat-openbsd tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
default-mysql-client default-mysql-server mariadb-client-10.1
mariadb-server-10.1 mysql-client mysql-server
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,748 B/11.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 125 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian stretch/main amd64 default-mysql-    client all 1.0.2 [3,050 B]
Get:2 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian stretch/main amd64 mysql-client amd64     5.5.9999+default [1,698 B]
Fetched 4,748 B in 0s (92.8 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-client-10.1.
(Reading database ... 290851 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-mariadb-client-10.1_10.1.26-0+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-client-10.1 (10.1.26-0+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server-10.1.
Preparing to unpack .../1-mariadb-server-10.1_10.1.26-0+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.26-0+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package default-mysql-client.
Preparing to unpack .../2-default-mysql-client_1.0.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking default-mysql-client (1.0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package default-mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../3-default-mysql-server_1.0.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking default-mysql-server (1.0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
Preparing to unpack .../4-mysql-client_5.5.9999+default_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (5.5.9999+default) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../5-mysql-server_5.5.9999+default_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.5.9999+default) ...
Setting up mariadb-client-10.1 (10.1.26-0+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47+b1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.26-0+deb9u1) ...
Setting up default-mysql-client (1.0.2) ...
Setting up default-mysql-server (1.0.2) ...
Setting up mysql-server (5.5.9999+default) ...
Setting up mysql-client (5.5.9999+default) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u4) ...
```

Is there any way I can install only MySQL-server? Or that MariaDB thing must be installed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120178/whats-the-difference-between-mariadb-and-mysql - unless you have a really good reason for preferring MySQL over MariaDB (which is likely to be corporate demands) then you're better off with MariaDB.

Comment: MariaDB is the default Mysql-like database provided with Debian 9. You can trace the package depdenencies easily here: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/mysql-client and https://packages.debian.org/stretch/mysql-server . As you can see the mysql-client and mysql-server packages are effectively just aliases for the mariadb packages. This change was introduced with Debian 9, from what I can gather by reading online. If you want/need to use actual MySQL you can enable the official mysql repo: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Comment: Thank you guys, Quentin and ADyson.

Comment: @Quentin - That SE link started 7 years ago.  The general thrust is still correct, but there have been a lot of changes/improvements in both MySQL and MariaDB since then.  That is, the forks have diverged more than they were 7 years ago.

Comment: @RickJames — Perhaps you could write a better answer for the linked question?

Answer (score 4):

You go to http://repo.mysql.com/ and choose a version

I have debian 9 so I choose

```
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
```

Then you will be asked what you desire to install ... you say `mysql Server`

[image]

then you go as usual ...

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

and the rest you know probably ...